# Applying a style to "everything"

Tags: css, html

I'm using CSS to style my webpage.  I want to apply the following CSS to every element on my form **without having to set is individually for each element**.

I was hoping there was some kind of wild card character that I could apply here.

Here is the CSS that I am trying to make global:

```
.noSelect 
    {
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -khtml-user-select: none;
        -moz-user-select: none;
        -o-user-select: none;
        user-select: none;
        cursor: default;
        margin:0px;
        padding:0px;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the [universal selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#universal-selector)

Comment: Are you implying that I can just say { CSS HERE } with nothing (or an *) in front?  let me try it real quick.

Comment: No, I'm not saying you can use 'nothing'. You have to use the universal selector: `*`

Comment: @DalexL, you would write `* { ..css attributes here.. }`. Example: I use the selector frequently, when I want to see borders around everything for debugging purposes.

Comment: in some browsers disabling ALL the select causing an issue.. like textbox- try and select something-- it becomes like a readonly text box.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use the universal selector

```
html * { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

What kind of tags are you using in your form? You could try starting with this:

```
.noSelect, input, textarea, select, label
{
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -o-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    cursor: default;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
```

Comment: Don't you mean: `.noSelect input, .noSelect textarea, .noSelect select, .noSelect label { ...`?

Comment: No. I dont know what his HTML looks like so I wasnt trying to make any assumptions about heirarchy.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your selector.  Instead of .noSelect, you want something like:

```
#formID *
{
  /* your css */
}
```

If you're doing it dynamically through jquery or something, just add/remove a class from the root:

```
#formID.inactive *
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
.noSelect * {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -o-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  cursor: default;
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
}
```

With the following form code:

```
<form class="noSelect">
  <!-- stuff here -->
</form>
```

Unfortunately the `disabled` attribute cannot be applied to a form (officially). But perhaps it's better to do something like this

```
<form>
  <label for="i1">Label 1</label>
  <input type="text" id="i1" disabled>
  <label for="i2">Label 2</label>
  <input type="checkbox" value="1" id="i2" disabled>
  <!-- More inputs and stuff. -->
</form>
```

If you're using jQuery you can apply the `disabled` attribute with the following in a `<script>` block:

```
// pre jQuery 1.6 (eg 1.5.x, 1.4.x, 1.3.x, ...)
$('form :input').attr('disabled', true);
// jQuery 1.6+
$('form :input').prop('disabled', true);
```